# Free tool that can execute large SQL scripts

Tags: gratis, software-development, sql, h2

I have a SQL script that is too large to run it in my usual DB tool (dbvisualizer).
Unfortunately I don't have access to the purchase version of dbvisualizer which would allow me to run large scripts in the command line tool.

**What is a good free tool to run a large SQL script in?**

In my case large means: script file >200MB, 1 CREATE statement and lots of INSERTs. Intended to be run on a local H2 database.

Comment: Fot which DBMS? Most (all?) of them provide a CLI e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Comment: It's a local H2 database. I added that information to the question.

Comment: Cut the sql file up into small chunks. If there are lots of inserts, split the file up into 4 50MB files or so. To get acccess to the "purchase version", you can purchase it.

Comment: I already tried dividing the file in two parts, this didn't help. If I can't find another solution I will try even smaller parts but a more elegant solution would be better. As for the purchase version: my employer won't provide the  funds to buy it. Otherwise I'd be happy to, it's a great tool.

Comment: How about reading and executing your scripts lines by lines? Any server-side language would do the job.

Comment: How about mysql or mariadb (it has a new name)?

Comment: You want to run a 200Mb script, presumably with the blessing of your employer, and he doesn't want to pay for it?   (Shakes head)  So how much time are you going to waste (at what $ rate), before your employer buys you the tool instead of wasting his money avoiding the obvious solution?

Comment: Ira, if you are suggesting, that this is short sighted and a total waste of time and money, you are so right. Unfortunately there are companies were "this is not in our tool chain" is more important than "this would be the most efficient (and cheapest) way to do this."

Comment: Use a file splutter. Google's first hit, http://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit/ looks like it could do it. Just split after every 1,000th INSERT